# OptionsPattern[] Vs. opt___

Tags: options, optional-arguments

Since version 6 I've been dutifully using `OptionsPattern[]` instead of the original `opts___` for passing options to functions.

I have just recently run into some restrictions when using `OptionsPattern[]` while I believe using `opts___` would not have these restrictions.

I am wondering if anyone knows the advantages of using the `OptionsPattern[]` versus the pre-Version 6 method of just passing a `opts___` as the last argument of a function?

Example:
Pre-Version 6:

```
f[x_, opts___]:= (* code that manually uses the opts passed *)
```

Post-Version 6:

```
f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := (* code that extracts options from OptionValue[] *)
```

Comment: Could you share the *specific* situation that gave rise to the question, i.e. where you found `opts___` to be advantageous over `OptionsPattern[]`?

Comment: Why not use both? `f[x_, opts: OptionsPattern[]]` helps if you want to do things like `FilterRules` and stuff.

Comment: "I have just recently run into some restrictions when using `OptionsPattern[]` while I believe using `opts___` would not have these restrictions."  It's not clear what you mean.  Without describing what it is that you believe cannot be done with `OptionsPattern[]`, we can only keep guessing and cannot provide a useful answer.

Comment: I should say that I would have a really hard time if I had to think of a case where `opt___` is really better than `OptionsPattern[]`. I can't recall a case when I needed it.

Comment: @Kuba It is not necessary to set `Options` to use `OptionsPattern[]`. It is useful for pure matching, and `OptionValue` can extract default values from an explicit list (instead of from `Options`).

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that the question, as written, is too theoretical. @M.Decker do you have a concrete problem?  If yes, someone can show how to use `OptionsPattern[]` and `opt___` to solve it, and compare *through a concrete example*.

Comment: @Szabolcs right, I'm deleting my comment as I get confused about invalid option message.

Comment: The only situation I've run into where `OptionsPattern` didn't do what I expected is ```In[8]:= MatchQ[{fun[a, b, "opt1" -> v1, "opt2" -> v2], 
  fun[b, a]}, {fun[_, _, OptionsPattern[]] ..}]

Out[8]= False```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, in its current form, it is not possible to give a meaningful answer. I (and others) have commented and until the question is made clearer, this should be put on hold.

Comment: Please don't close this question quite yet.  I believe I can show an example where opt___ works and OptionsPattern[] doesn't, but I need some free time.

Comment: One problem is indeed with the companion function `OptionValue` that will not evaluate within `Hold`, while old style `ReplaceAll` will act without restriction.

Comment: M. Decker are you aware that you can do this: `Options@foo={a->3};
foo[options:OptionsPattern[]]:={Hold[a]/.{options}/.Options@foo,Hold@OptionValue@a}`?

Comment: Pierre ALBAREDE,  Thank you all for responding.

The specific example is passing a pure function as an option that uses other option values as the arguments to a pure function passed in an option.   Allowing to create a function as an option, where the arguments are values of other options.

I find this impossible with OptionPattern[ ] because of how OptionPattern scopes the variables.

Comment: I know this thread has been criticized for being too general.  But I don't think it is unreasonable to ask why one would use OptionsPattern[].  What advantage does it serve over the pre-6 version.