# OptionsPattern does not match rule with compound left hand side

Tags: pattern-matching, options

`OptionsPattern` was introduced in Mathematica v6 so I have finally decided to give a try.

Look at this program:

```
Clear@foo;
foo[options : OptionsPattern[]] := {options}
foo[k2 -> 3]
foo[Indexed[k, 2] -> 3]
```

out:

```
{k2 -> 3}
foo[Indexed[k, {2}] -> 3]
```

*The rule with compound left hand side has not matched* `OptionsPattern[]`.

You can replace Indexed by any function (`Power`, `Subscript`), it will be the same.

Now compare with old style option pattern:

```
Clear@foo;
foo[options___Rule] := {options}
foo[k2 -> 3]
foo[Indexed[k, 2] -> 3]
```

out:

```
{k2 -> 3}
{Indexed[k, {2}] -> 3}
```

Matching occurs in all cases.

Is there a bug in `OptionsPattern`?

Comment: It may be the same sort of limitation that prevents using compound expression as variable in `Manipulate` or `Plot`.

Answer (score 8):

The whole question is based on the wrong premise that old-style options were just simply arbitrary rules. This is not the case, in the past the special `OptionQ` predicate was used to distinguish options from general rules.

With proper option-testing, your example would look like:

```
Clear@foo;
foo[options___Rule?OptionQ] := {options}
foo[k2 -> 3]
foo[Indexed[k, 2] -> 3]
```

which gives the output identical to what `OptionsPattern[]` method does.

Comment: Yes, I was abusing the option system to pass arbitrary rules.  It is not a bug, it is a feature.

Answer (score 4):

When `OptionsPattern[]` is used, `OptionValue@k2` is supposed to work too, so behind the scene there is something like

```
k2/:OptionValue@k2=3
```

which fails if `k2` is replaced by `f1[k2]`: you would get a "Tag too deep" error.

So the new system has simpler syntax but is less general.

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174544/optionspattern-vs-opt#comment605524_174544

Comment: Doesn't really explain `String` options, since they cannot be used with `TagSet`.  Option names were originally `Symbol`.  Then they seemed to realize that the expansion of functions and their options might flood the system namespace with an overwhelming number of symbols.  So they expanded to allow `String` option names.  Those are the only alternatives in system commands.

Comment: Yes indeed `OptionQ["method" -> xx]` returns `True` so my explanation cannot be complete.